# Store multiple inputs in multiple variables in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I need to make a loop about this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3>&1;
result=$(dialog --inputbox "Scan S/N" 10 23 2>&1 1>&3);
result1=$(dialog --inputbox "Scan S/N" 10 23 2>&1 1>&3);
result2=$(dialog --inputbox "Scan S/N" 10 23 2>&1 1>&3);
exec 3>$-;
clear
echo $result;
echo $result1;
echo $result2;
```

And would be great to have a varible where i can select how many times will the loop run...

I dont have to tell you im pretty newbie in this hehe, thanks in advance.
JB

Comment: based on your minimal description of the use-case, you don't need to worry about `exec n>&n` code. Leave them out, it will just confuse things. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you talk about a variable number of related variables, you want an array.

```
n=3
for ((i=0; i<n; i++)); do
    results+=( $(dialog --inputbox "Scan S/N" 10 23 2>&1)) 
done

# individual results can be accessed with ${results[i]} for i=0,1,...,n-1
for res in "${results[@]}"; do
  echo "$res"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic way to loop and count is :

```
c=0
while true; do
  echo "count $c"
  ((c++))
  ((c==100)) && break
done

echo DONE
```